# Strange behavior using WCF and ServiceModelEx Service Bus

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, publish-subscribe, servicemodelex

I'm using the Service Bus portion of ServiceModelEx. (and using AppFabric for auto-starting WCF services). I'm getting some strange behavior...

Basically, the first time I call into the service bus, all the proper events fire down the chain (verified by looking in the database and seeing the recorded values).

But on subsequent calls, nothing happens. It's like the events never fire...

The .svclogs don't show anything helpful, in fact, they don't even register the subsequent events.

The windows event logs do however show the following errors for each of the services subscribed to the bus:

```
WebHost failed to process a request.
 Sender Information: System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment+HostingManager/777031
 Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service '/AcmeWidgets.WidgetFactory.Subscribers.WidgetBuilder/BuildService.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: The type 'AcmeWidgets.WidgetFactory.Subscribers.WidgetBuilder.BuildService', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The type 'AcmeWidgets.WidgetFactory.Subscribers.WidgetBuilder.BuildService', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.ActivateService(String normalizedVirtualPath)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureServiceAvailableFast(String relativeVirtualPath)
 Process Name: w3wp
 Process ID: 3052
```

I know the service attribute value is correct, obviously because it runs correctly the first time.

Any ideas???

Edit 1: To add to this strange behavior, if I 'Rebuild' the solution in Visual Studio, the first call into the bus works, and all the events down the chain fire, and then all subsequent calls fail, again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code-path you show the stack trace here is not specific to Service Bus. This is an activation error. It looks to me as if there's a type-load error here. I would try to take a look at that first using fuslogvw